# "node app.js" not working for "mongoose" code

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    ratinn: Number,
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Apple",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Pretty solid as a fruit."
});

fruit.save();

const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
   
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection('documents');
    //Find some documents
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, fruits) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Found the following records");
        console.log(fruits)
        callback(fruits);
    });
}
```

Above is the code written and yet, when I run "node app.js", nothing shows.

Comment: I don't where you call `findDoucments` and also I don't suppose that `save` is sync function.

Comment: So apparently, nothing shows up when I run "node app.js", when I opened up mongosh and run "db.fruits.find()", it worked by displaying the data. Again, I don't know why nothing showed up when the "node app.js" code was run.

Comment: fruitsDB> db.fruits.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62e418a85ed796c8f4f06a80"),
    name: 'Apple',
    review: 'Pretty solid as a fruit.',
    __v: 0
  }
]

Comment: That's the expected data which was displayed in the "mongosh"

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to call findDocuments in the end.
So, it can be like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({ name: String, ratinn: Number, review: String });

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({ name: "Apple", rating: 7, review: "Pretty solid as a fruit." });

fruit.save();

const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {

// Get the documents collection
const collection = db.collection('documents'); // I am not sure where did you declare `db` here

//Find some documents

//Since you are using mongoose, so call find({}) using your Fruit model
Fruit.find({}).toArray(function(err, fruits) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(fruits)
    callback(fruits);
});
}

findDocuments();
```